# postgres authorization with username plus ip address possible?

Tags: postgresql, virtual-machine

I am running several virtual machines which all have a local postgresql instance. This is great when cloning such a machine - the local db will also be cloned and it is not possible to compromise the master vm database content.

For performance reasons I want to use a central postgresql database for all virtual machines but I absolutely must make sure that a cloned virtual machine can't touch its master data, even if it contains the same username and password. That would be easy to accomplish if the client's IP address is somehow used during authentication to postgres.

In other words, I want to deny access to postgresql if the client's ip address does not match, even if the username and password match, to avoid that my cloned vm destroys the data of the vm it is cloned from.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL does host-based authentication through the [`pg_hba.conf` file](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).

To reject any connection from a particular IP address, for example `10.0.0.1`, you may put this at the beginning of the file:

> host all all 10.0.0.1 reject

It can also reject a range of addresses

> host all all 10.0.0.0/24 reject

Or if you prefer the opposite way, enumerating the authorized addresses instead of using `reject`

> host all all 192.168.0.1 md5

A host that is not authorized by any rule will be rejected, and the rules are processed in the order of the file.

Comment: so what I need to do is for each virtual machine I have to add one row like "host user01_db user01 192.168.0.1/32 md5", the next vm would get "host user02_db user02 192.168.0.2/32 md5". When I clone user01's vm so that it has ip address 192.168.0.3, he can never access user01_db, is that right?

Comment: @nn4l: not sure it's what you need. What it does is **allowing** connections with a password to user0Xdb for user0X from 192.168.0.X. Yet your question may be interpreted as if you're only interested in **denying** access rather than allowing.

Comment: exactly. I want to deny access if a user is now accessing from a different IP address. So when I clone a virtual machine and run this on a different ip address, it can't mess with the original data.

Comment: @nn4l: ok for what you want to deny. Now what do you want to allow?

Comment: After I clone a vm, I have to add a new rule to the pg_hba.conf file that contains the new ip address.